# How to fix the java.util.NoSuchElementException error when reading text from a file using a scanner?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to find a certain string in a comma separated file with Java. After this, I want to print the next comma separated value in the file, and I don't know how to.

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class readinfile {

```
public static void main (String[] args)  {
    String filepath = "C://adi//test1.txt"; 
    String searchTerm = "glove";
    readRecord(searchTerm, filepath);
} 

public static void readRecord(String searchTerm, String filepath) {
    boolean found = false;
    String clothing1 =  ""; 
    String clothing2 = ""; 
    String clothing3 = "";

    Scanner x = new Scanner((filepath)); 
    x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

    while(x.hasNext() && !found) {

        clothing1 = x.next(); 
        clothing2 = x.next(); 
        clothing3 = x.next(); 

        if(ID.equals(searchTerm)) {
            found = true;
            x.close(); 
        }

    } 

    if (found) {
        System.out.println(searchTerm + "was found in the text file");

    } else {
        System.out.println("Record not found");
    } 
}
```

}

The error message that I always recieve is java.util.NoSuchElementException, which seems to be a problem with the Scanner. I am not sure how to fix this and am hoping for some help.

Comment: what is ID? compilation error.'

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. What is `ID`? Are you sure that each line doesn't have different fields and not just `clothing1`, `clothing2` and `clothing3`? Your error indicates that the number of fields is actually not a multiple of 3 since you are checking `hasNext()` once but you have 3 `next()` calls in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have three `x.next()` inside your `while(x.hasNext())` loop. So if you have one or two items left at the start of the loop, the loop will run and you'll try to get three items, which is probably why you're getting that exception.

A simple though not very elegant solution would be something like:

```
while(x.hasNext() && !found) {
    if(x.hasNext()){clothing1 = x.next();} 
    if(x.hasNext()){clothing2 = x.next();}
    if(x.hasNext()){clothing3 = x.next();}

    if(ID.equals(searchTerm)) {
        found = true;
        x.close(); 
    }

}
```

You'd still want to do something about the possibility that `clothing2` and `clothing3` might not be assigned.

You'd be far better off doing this with an array, but I don't have time to explain that now.